# CSS Border top is not working

Tags: html, css, border

I've been trying to put a border top on a bunch of hyperlinks to separate them from the title (for a school homework) but it's not working and I'm trying this since over an hour already.

This is the CSS code of the #menu which contains my hyperlinks:

```css
#menu {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px #669999;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 3</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 4</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 5</a>
</div>
```

[image: menu]

This is the picture how it looks like. (Yes I know it's ugly, but I have to work with the instructions)

Comment: You didn't specify `solid`, so it's defaulting to `1px #699 none`, which is still no border.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I don't think the OP has enough rep to post images.

Comment: Indeed...you **must** state a `border-style`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `solid` in between, else the default value doesn't have anything.

```css
border-top: 1px solid #669999;
```

Check the initial values to be:

[image]

**Working Snippet**

```css
#menu {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #669999;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 3</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 4</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 5</a>
</div>
```

And not a good idea to use `&nbsp;` for laying out purposes. Try using `margin`:

```css
#menu {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #669999;
}

#menu a {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 1</a> |
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 2</a> |
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 3</a> |
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 4</a> |
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

your `border` syntax is incorrect, is missing the style of `border`,

should be `<br-width> || <br-style> || <color>`

Check `border` syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border)

**Notes**

- `&nbsp;` isn't meant to create spaces, use instead `margin` in CSS
- I shortened your `padding` and your hex colors

---

```css
body {
  background: darkgreen
}
#menu {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #699;
}
#menu a {
  margin: 0 5px;
  color:#fff
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 1</a>|
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 2</a>|
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 3</a>|
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 4</a>|
  <a href="#">HYPERLINK 5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your border-top is property is missing the border-style attribute. Try the following. You can find out more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-top

```
#menu {
  ...
  border-top: 1px solid #669999;
}
```