# Centering vertical in header navbar

Tags: html, css, alignment

I created a navbar in my header and aligned it with another element so that they were centered. However, after adding an image to the header, one of the elements is no longer centered:

```css
#header nav {
  display: inline;
}
#header {
  background: #5D6D63;
  padding: 28px 0 26px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}
#header nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 46px;
}
a[href^="#"] {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-decoration: none
}
a[href="#top"] {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <a href="#top">Name</a>
  <a href="https://github.com/">
    <img src="assets/imgs/GitHub-Mark-Light-64px.png" alt="GitHub" height="24" width="24">
  </a>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The issue is the vertical alignment of the Name anchor tag. It should be centered with the the github image and the navbar. If I remove the github image, it works fine and it is aligned. Why is the github image causing the Name anchor tag to be pushed down a few pixels?

Here are pictures to show it misaligned (with image) and aligned (without image)

[image: Misaligned]

[image: Aligned]

Comment: Make a jsFiddle to help us understand your problem

Comment: You'd think there would be an appropriate dupe out there for vertically-aligning elements like this...but man, so hard to find in the sea of marginally related questions. XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by j08691 (and others), the property you're looking for is `vertical-align:middle`.

One caveat, however: you have to remember that both the image and the anchor tag next to it by default have `vertical-align:baseline` - meaning, if you only vertically center one of them, its baseline will become vertically aligned to the center of the sibling element, rather than its middle. (Depending on which element you apply this to, this could arguable worsen your alignment problem.)

Here are the modified/added style blocks you'll be needing:

```css
a[href="#top"] {
  margin-left: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#header img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
#header nav {
  display: inline;
}
#header {
  background: #5D6D63;
  padding: 28px 0 26px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}
#header nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 46px;
}
a[href^="#"] {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-decoration: none
}
a[href="#top"] {
  margin-left: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#header img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <a href="#top">Name</a>
  <a href="https://github.com/">
    <img src="assets/imgs/GitHub-Mark-Light-64px.png" alt="GitHub" height="24" width="24">
  </a>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is what I was missing. Before posting this question I tried adding the vertical-align: middle to the img and noticed it still wasn't centered. Didn't realize I needed to add it to the text as well. Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 2):

Because the default [vertical alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) for inline elements is `baseline` and you want `middle`. So add a rule like:

```
img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```css
#header nav{
    display:inline;
}
#header {
    background: #5D6D63;
    padding: 28px 0 26px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;

}
#header nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 46px; 
}
a[href^="#"]{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-decoration: none
}

a[href="#top"] {
    margin-left:100px;
}
img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
 <header id="header"> 
        <a href="#top">Name</a>
        <a href="https://github.com/">
            <img src="http://www.uoyabause.org/images/logos/GitHub-Mark-Light-64px.png" alt="GitHub" height="24" width="24">
        </a>
        <nav id="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>       
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Seriously? Answering this question? Even your answer doesn't have the right one.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I don't see a problem with helping the user. And what's wrong with the answer?

Comment: I would comment the answer and close as too broad... Even that helps...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why is it too broad? Seems pretty obvious what the OP's issue is.

Comment: That's the exact reason why it is too broad. It is like "How should I center text?" - Toooooo broad.

Comment: @j08691 Another stackoverflow question I read that was similar stated that vertical-align doesn't work as intended without a table which is why I removed it. Is there a reason why some people seem to not suggest using it without a table?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629561/css-vertical-align-middle-not-working

Comment: @PraveenKumar You answered this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278498/css-border-top-is-not-working/37278582#37278582), if you're implying, that's an easy one, and should be a comment instead. It's not too broad. People make it too broad by creating a lot of layouts. In this case doesn't need that, simple `vertical-align` is the solution

Comment: @EricS Oftentimes the tabular approach is because they're trying to center block-level elements vertically. However, vertically aligning inline/inline-block-level elements relative to each other may be done with simply `vertical-align`.

Comment: @Serlite Even this approach doesn't seem to actually align the image with the rest of the content. It's not centered. It's better than before so I'll use it.

Comment: @EricS In fact, you need to apply `vertical-align:middle` to both the image, and the anchor tag next to the image. Was writing an answer regarding that, wasn't sure if I should post it though. (Let me know if you need to see that.)

Comment: @Serlite That was what I was missing. Thanks

Comment: @EricS Super - I'll add the answer in case anyone else runs into this issue, since it can be a bit of a gotcha (and the info I want to add is a bit too substantial to edit in...).

Answer (score 0):

Make Image Verticla alignment:
Add Css Like this:

```
a img{
   vertical-align:middle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display your `#header` as `flex` and use  `align-content: center;`.

```css
#header nav{
    display:inline;
}
#header {
    display: flex; /* NEW: Makes the container as flexbox */
    align-content: center; /* NEW: Center the items inside the container vertically */
    background: #5D6D63;
    padding: 28px 0 26px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;

}
#header nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 46px; 
}
a[href^="#"]{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-decoration: none
}

a[href="#top"] {
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header"> 
        <a href="#top">Name</a>
        <a href="https://github.com/">
            <img src="http://www.uoyabause.org/images/logos/GitHub-Mark-Light-64px.png" alt="GitHub" height="24" width="24">
        </a>
        <nav id="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>       
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Add jQuery, Bootstrap CSS, and also a rocket launcher code as well. :P Man, why do you need to complicate things, when you can achieve it using `vertical-align`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Well... I am not a friend of using libraries for this kind of approachs. I just put another solution with new CSS different from `j08691`'s one.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, I knew. I just was following your play :) And yeah, I think it is always a good way to have different solutions and let the OP choose the best one. Of course, in this case, that can be fixed with a single line, it could be a bit redundant.